# Old blog/ and blog/feed/ URLs not working after moving blog to top-level via .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

For a long time I served my blog from http://www.murrayc.com/blog/, with the wordpress installation in /home/murrayc/murrayc.com/blog/. Now I've moved it to http://www.murrayc.com/, without moving the wordpress installation on the filesystem.

I did that by:

- Changing the "Site Address (URL)", in Settings->General, to http://www.murrayc.com. I kept the "WordPress Address (URL)" as http://www.murrayc.com/blog
- Adding a RedirectRule in my top-level .htaccess at /home/murrayc/murrayc.com/, so that, for instance, permalink/something could be used instead of blog/permalink/something. The older blog/permalinks still seem to work too.

However, some old links are not working.
http://www.murrayc.com/blog/ takes you to a page that happens to mention blogs, presumably via Wordpress's attempt to guess what you want. Likewise, http://www.murrayc.com/blog/feed takes you to the comments feed for one old blog post.

With the rules added by Wordpress (after changing the "Site Address URL", I think), this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/temp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm using Wordpress 3.5.1, the latest release, via Dreamhost's 1-click install, which updates automatically.

This feels like a bug in Wordpress. Maybe it's misinterpreting URLs that it gets at some point that contain blog/blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first Part of your `.htaccess`, just use the standard WordPress configuration.

The main problem is, you need to create a new `index.php` in the `root` directory of your webspace, containing the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

You also need to create a `.htaccess` file in your root directory, containing the standard WordPress `.htaccess`, and then everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, removing everything from my top-level .htaccess other than the part added by Wordpress, but the problems with blog/ and blog/feed/ remain.

Comment: Did you alter your `index.php` in the TopLevel? the important part is the last line, where you define from which directory `wp-blog-header.php` is included.

Comment: No, I used an index.php file with exactly the content that you suggested. My wordpress is at blog/, so it seems OK. It's working otherwise, though I don't notice any difference to how it was with just the .htaccess.

Comment: However, I do notice that my http://www.murrayc.com/feed is now as broken as http://www.murrayc.com/blog/feed , so I'll have to change things back if I don't figure this out. I need at least one working feed URL.

Comment: Hm, the Link [http://www.murrayc.com/feed/](http://www.murrayc.com/feed/) seems to work for your setup. As your Images are delivered from the `blog` subdirectory, I suppose you got the solution?

Comment: No, http://www.murrayc.com/feed/ works again because I reverted to the .htaccess. I couldn't leave the site with no working feed URL. http://www.murrayc.com/blog/feed/ remains broken.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use 301 redirects, as now there is no blog directory, but it is assumed to be as root.
You have to inform server that these are old urls and should be matched to new one's. You can do this using .htaccess as code below,

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://www.murrayc.com/blog http://www.murrayc.com/
Redirect 301 http://www.murrayc.com/blog/feed http://www.murrayc.com/feed
```

also there are plugins for these.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've tried placing that (and with lines for the URLs ending in /) at the start of the .htaccess file. I've tried it with wget, so I doubt that any cache is involved.

Answer (score -1):

Set up .htaccess correctly, it's all about it.
We had such a task on the site https://alexsend.com/blog

Comment: Well yes this does look like an htaccess problem but just telling OP to do it correctly isn't that helpful. What specifically is wrong with the htaccess they posted? How would you correct it?